# form_for params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I need to submit a form to an external URL, so I have this:

```
form_for(@task, :url => "https://www.external.com/Submit") do |f|)
    <%= f.hidden_field :assignmentId, :value => @assignment %>
    <%= link_to image_tag(@imagelocation) %>
....
```

I am using `form_for`, because I need to access to my controller variables.

The external server looks for a param, `assignmentId`. When the form is submitted, the param is actually available as

```
params[:task][:assignmentId]
```

which fails to pass validation on the external server.

How do I resolve this? How do I access variables from my controller and pass 'naked' params to the external server?

[edit] Here's what the submit params looks like

> utf8=%E2%9C%93&_method=put&task%5BassignmentId%5D=2LVQ39Z0B6UWI8NXYWJTYRKGQXIMXN&task%5Boutput%5D=carpet&commit=Post

I want it to not have the task referenced.

Comment: If you don't want to reference the task object, then use **form_tag** to render the form.

Comment: You could set the name of the field manually: `<%= f.hidden_field :assignmentId, :value => @assignment, :name => :assignmentId %>`, but it'd probably be better to just use `hidden_field_tag`.

Comment: Thanks Mischa, I used the hidden_field_tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `hidden_field_tag` instead of `f.hidden_field`. Btw, if you want this field to store assignment's id, you should use `@assignment.id`, not just `@assignment`.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :assignmentId, @assignment.id %>
```